# Webcam video recorder with resumable uploader

Tags: video-capture

I am developing a website in which video recording is the core feature. We would ideally want video recording to continue even if internet connection goes down. If user is recording the video and internet gets disconnected then the video may get locally saved and when internet connection resumes, the video gets uploaded to the server.

I have gone through some websites which provides APIs for recording video via webcam but they do not work even if internet connection goes down for a moment.

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I guess for your case you need to offer an off-line application rather online streaming solution, then later the user can upload the video. PresentationTube at http://presentationtube.com uses this technique. As they said: PresentationTube offers a PowerPoint presentation recorder and video sharing network to help teachers, students and business professionals produce and share presentations in video format.